# What am I doing wrong with vspace

Tags: vertical-spacing

In the MWE below (LuaLaTex), why `\vspace*{1pt}` causes such a huge vertical space?

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}

\begin{document}
% \vspace*{1pt}
\begin{center}
    \Huge{Test text.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because `\begin{center}` introduces vertical padding which is however ignored at the start of a page.

Comment: \vspace* inserts an invisible rule and so your center is no longer at the begin of the page.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `\Huge` is a switch and does not take an argument. Use `\Huge Test text.` or `{\Huge Test text.}` if you want to restrict the change to a certain group.

Comment: You can avoid the problem by moving `\vspace*{1pt}` into the `center` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want exactly one point of space above the title, then you need some deeper control on spacing.

With `\vspace*{1pt}\begin{center}` the standard space above `center` is not removed because it's preceded by something that must not be removed at a page break (the start of a document counts as a page break). Thus you get the total of `1pt` plus the `\topsep`.

On the other hand, you probably don't actually want `center`, but only centering the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1pt}% the space you want
\vspace{-\topskip}% remove the topskip
\begingroup\centering\Huge
Test text\par
\endgroup
\addvspace{\topsep}% or what you need

Some other text follows.

\end{document}
```

Note that you need something more than just `\vspace*{1pt}`.

[image]